# Error Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be calle d on 'WidgetsBinding? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, binding

les comento tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo una App que se llama NextHour, realmente soy nuevo en esto de la programación y cuando intento hacer `flutter run` me salen los siguientes errores.

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/smart_refresher.dart:525:31: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be calle
d on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/smart_refresher.dart:673:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be calle
d on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/smart_refresher.dart:756:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be calle
d on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
```

Veo que dice que intente usando `?` sin embargo aunque ya localice las lineas de codigo que me menciona no se donde colocarlo.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Dejo fragmentos de las lineas que el codigo indica:

Linea 525

```
 // TODO: implement initState
    if (widget.controller.initialRefresh) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```

Linea 673

```
 ?.setCanDrag(false);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (needMove) {
```

**Actualización**

He realizado el cambio sugerido por Manuel, al parecer funciono ya no aparecen los errores anteriores, pero ahora me saltan estos

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/scroll/custom_scroll_bar.dart:24:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'.
        thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:865:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RawScrollbar({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/scroll/custom_scroll_bar.dart:35:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'.
      thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart:75:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scrollbar({
        ^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
```

El código al que hacen referencia los errores es el siguiente:

cistom_scroll_bar.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (this.scrollbarStyle?.thumbColor != null) {
      return RawScrollbar(
        controller: this.controller,
        thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
        thickness: this.scrollbarStyle?.thickness,
        radius: this.scrollbarStyle?.radius,
        thumbColor: this.scrollbarStyle?.thumbColor,
        child: this.child,
        notificationPredicate: notificationPredicate,
      );
    }
```

scroll.dart

```
/// must not be null.
  const RawScrollbar({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
```

custom_scroll_bar.dart linea 35

```
return Scrollbar(
      controller: this.controller,
      thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
      thickness: this.scrollbarStyle?.thickness,
      radius: this.scrollbarStyle?.radius,
      child: this.child,
      notificationPredicate: notificationPredicate,
    );
```

C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart:75:9

```
/// thumb without a radius.
  const Scrollbar({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
```

[image: Detalles]

Comment: Prueba añadiendo "?" a la llamada del método "addPostFrameCallback". WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback

Comment: Que versión de flutter estás usando?

Comment: @diegoveloper flutter-2.10.3-stable

Comment: @Manuel Si funciono ya no me salen esos errores, pero ahora salen unos nuevos, ya he actualizado la pregunta con los nuevos detalles, Gracias por su apoyo de verdad compañeros, recién me meto en el mundo de Android.

Comment: el ide te muestra errores antes de compilar? si es así puedes agregar una imagen

Comment: @diegoveloper puse una captura de pantalla no se si es lo que necesitas?

Comment: hmm esos son errores del lado de android, quería ver los errores del código Dart que te muestra? por cierto, veo que estas usando el package `horizontal_data_table`, probaste instalando la última versión? https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table/changelog

Comment: @diegoveloper Como puedo ver esos errores? porque cualquier archivo Dart que abro no me muestra ninguno, intente poner la version 4.1.1 y volvieron los errores que había al inicio de nuevo

Comment: Creo que hay problemas de incompatibilidad entre la versión que estás usando de Flutter y alguno de tus packages. Podrías probar a hacer flutter clean, flutter pub cache repair y flutter pub get, en ese orden. Otra cosilla sería saber si todas las dependencias que estás usando son null-safety y en caso de no serlo, intentar actualizarlas a null-safety.

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez el mensaje de error indica el problema, no se están permitiendo valores null en WidgetsBinding.instance, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas el error:

```
Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

En idioma español indica:

> Error: No se puede llamar al método 'addPostFrameCallback' en
> 'WidgetsBinding?' porque es potencialmente nula.

La solución es usar '?', para permitir valores nulos en `WidgetsBinding.instance` aquí:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```