# Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'. thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Tengo una App que se llama NextHour, pero al tratar compilarla me salen los siguientes errores y no se que pueda ser ya que soy nuevo en esto de Android y programación en AndroidStudio.

Espero alguien me pueda hechar un cable porque ya llevo mucho y no se que pueda ser.

Gracias de antemano

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/scroll/custom_scroll_bar.dart:24:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'.
        thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:865:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RawScrollbar({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-3.7.0/lib/scroll/custom_scroll_bar.dart:35:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'.
      thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart:75:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scrollbar({
        ^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
```

El código al que hacen referencia los errores es el siguiente:

cistom_scroll_bar.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (this.scrollbarStyle?.thumbColor != null) {
      return RawScrollbar(
        controller: this.controller,
        thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
        thickness: this.scrollbarStyle?.thickness,
        radius: this.scrollbarStyle?.radius,
        thumbColor: this.scrollbarStyle?.thumbColor,
        child: this.child,
        notificationPredicate: notificationPredicate,
      );
    }
```

scroll.dart

```
/// must not be null.
  const RawScrollbar({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
```

custom_scroll_bar.dart linea 35

```
return Scrollbar(
      controller: this.controller,
      thumbVisibility: this.scrollbarStyle?.isAlwaysShown ?? false,
      thickness: this.scrollbarStyle?.thickness,
      radius: this.scrollbarStyle?.radius,
      child: this.child,
      notificationPredicate: notificationPredicate,
    );
```

C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart:75:9

```
/// thumb without a radius.
  const Scrollbar({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
```

Comment: tienes actualizado el paquete? o tienes actualizado flutter?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be calle d on 'WidgetsBinding? Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543001/error-error-method-addpostframecallback-cannot-be-calle-d-on-widgetsbinding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto al error:

> Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'.

No se encuentra el parámetro, ya que estás usando una versión de `animated_custom_dropdown` para `flutter` 3 (3.0.1), debes usar como máximo la versión 1.2.1 de `animated_custom_dropdown`